# JQuery Triggering Tab Not Working Inside iFrame

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I am wondering why this works when put on my parent's HTML page:

```
$("#assessmentsTab").trigger("click");
```

but this does not work inside of my iFrame:

```
$("#assessmentsTab", window.parent.document).trigger("click");
```

Does anybody have any insight?

I have this function as well which works and successfully updates the CSS:

```
$("#assessmentsTab", window.parent.document).css({"color":"white", "background":"#3D4C53"});
```

**Fixed the issue!**

The correct syntax is:

```
window.parent.$("#assessmentsTab").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of it? Have you tried to trigger the activate event? `$("#assessmentsTab").trigger('tabsactivate');`

Comment: I tried `$("#assessmentsTab", window.parent.document).trigger('tabsactivate');` and `$("#assessmentsTab").trigger('tabsactivate');` ... no luck

Comment: I mean the js for updating the iframe, I assume that's the code you are running when the tabactivate is triggered

Comment: There is no js for updating the frame. There is a url in the `src` attribute and I want that to activate.

Comment: Ok a fiddle would help a lot here

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to see in the fiddle. What I posted is what I have. That jQuery is inside one of my iframes.

Comment: I can't picture how this works, it would be easier to debug if people can play around with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57046/discussion-between-nicolas-and-huangism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to trigger the click from within the iframe, to the parent

```
window.parent.$("#assessmentsTab").trigger('click')
```